# USB port causing device problems after new motherboard upgrade

Tags: usb, troubleshooting, port, case

I'm looking into a PC with an issue with one of the front USB ports (perhaps both).

It was working before a motherboard upgrade but since then, a USB drive was inserted, overheated and does not appear to be working. Then a phone (with USB charging) was plugged in, and the phone OS suspended. Removing and re-inserting the battery led to the phone (and hence battery) working, however the battery no longer charges (including with a wall charger).

It seems too much to be a coincidence and am wondering what the issue may be?

Ideas so far are short circuiting, or over-current to the USB ports.

Note: Did not occur to me, so details are not 100% accurate or complete. Feel free to ask for missing info that I may have forgotten though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the motherboard header that the front ports are plugged into.  If the port connectors are individual pins, check that they are all connected properly, and nothing is loose or frayed.

If everything seems snug, or if the connector is one single block, you need to verify that the motherboard header and port connector use the same pinouts.  You might need documentation on the motherboard and/or case.

[This page at FrontX](http://www.frontx.com/cpx108_2.html) is a good resource for common header pinouts.  To be sure which pinout you have, check your motherboard documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the 5V polarity is reversed. That would cause those sorts of problems. See pinout [here](http://pinouts.ru/Slots/USB_pinout.shtml) and check with a meter.